# How can I test that signed binaries will validate after Windows starts enforcing the new rules for SHA-1 certificates?

Tags: windows, code-signing, sha1, sha256

So... Microsoft has announced that [SHA-1 code signing certificates are deprecated](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32288.windows-enforcement-of-authenticode-code-signing-and-timestamping.aspx) as of January 1st 2016. I've done a fair bit of reading, I've had our certificate reissued using SHA-256 instead of SHA-1, and I think I understand how to dual-sign binaries so the signatures will validate on older versions of Windows that don't support SHA-256.

Here's the problem: despite the fact that these rules are supposed to apply from January 1st 2016, it doesn't look like Windows has started enforcing them yet. I've signed a number of EXE files with our old SHA-1 certificate, timestamped them with dates after January 1st 2016, and Windows still seems to consider the signatures to be valid (at least on fully-updated installations of Windows 7 and Windows 10). I've checked this by right-clicking on a signed file in Explorer, selecting "Properties", then going to the Digital Signatures tab and double-clicking the certificate. It tells me "The digital signature is OK".

Am I misunderstanding something here? Or is there some kind of tool that I can use to check that a signed EXE (or MSI, or whatever) will be valid after Windows stops accepting SHA-1 certificates? I don't want to release products now and discover at some point in the future that the signatures are no longer valid. That would be embarrassing.